# VBA simple macro to copy formulas

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to copy formulas from column into row. Formulas don't have $ signature in address so I cannot use special paste options, because it will change address in formulas of each cell.

I try to run macro, but it copy only last cell from column to everyone one in row.

```
Sub Zamiana()
For Each y In Range("A1:B1")
    For Each X In Range("A2:A3")
        y.Formula = X.Formula
    Next
Next
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance for help  :)

Answer (score 2):

A simple method is to transfer the formulas via a variant array and the `transpose` function.

Like this:

```
Sub TransposeFormulas()
    Dim rSrc As Range
    Dim rDst As Range
    Dim vSrc As Variant

    Set rSrc = Range("A1:B1")
    Set rDst = Range("A2") ' top left cell of destination

    vSrc = rSrc.Formula  ' copy source formulas into a variant array

    ' size the destination range and transpose formulas into it
    rDst.Resize(UBound(vSrc, 2), UBound(vSrc, 1)).Formula  = _
      Application.Transpose(vSrc)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

try adding two indexes, one for column and one for row and dropping a for loop,
something like this

```
Sub Zamiana()
iR = 1
iC = 0

For Each y In Range("A1:B1")
r = y.Row + iR
c = y.Column - iC     
Cells(r, c).Formula = y.Formula
iR = iR + 1
 iC = iC + 1

Next

End Sub
```